# Send Email through C++ using Gmail Account

Tags: c++, c, email, visual-c++, email-client

I want to send Email through C/C++ program using my Gmail Account. I find some resources but they were for LINUX and did not work for me. I want to do this on windows. Any sample program, or suggestion, how can I do this will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

// Insist on at least Winsock v1.1
const VERSION_MAJOR = 1;
const VERSION_MINOR = 1;

#define CRLF "\r\n"                 // carriage-return/line feed pair

void ShowUsage(void)
{
  cout << "Usage: SENDMAIL mailserv to_addr from_addr messagefile" << endl
       << "Example: SENDMAIL smtp.myisp.com rcvr@elsewhere.com my_id@mydomain.com message.txt" << endl;

  exit(1);
}

// Basic error checking for send() and recv() functions
void Check(int iStatus, char *szFunction)
{
  if((iStatus != SOCKET_ERROR) && (iStatus))
    return;

  cerr << "Error during call to " << szFunction << ": " << iStatus << " - " << GetLastError() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int         iProtocolPort        = 0;
  char        szSmtpServerName[64] = "";
  char        szToAddr[64]         = "";
  char        szFromAddr[64]       = "";
  char        szBuffer[4096]       = "";
  char        szLine[255]          = "";
  char        szMsgLine[255]       = "";
  SOCKET      hServer;
  WSADATA     WSData;
  LPHOSTENT   lpHostEntry;
  LPSERVENT   lpServEntry;
  SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;

  // Check for four command-line args
  if(argc != 5)
    ShowUsage();

  // Load command-line args
  lstrcpy(szSmtpServerName, argv[1]);
  lstrcpy(szToAddr, argv[2]);
  lstrcpy(szFromAddr, argv[3]);

  // Create input stream for reading email message file
  ifstream MsgFile(argv[4]);

  // Attempt to intialize WinSock (1.1 or later)
  if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(VERSION_MAJOR, VERSION_MINOR), &WSData))
  {
    cout << "Cannot find Winsock v" << VERSION_MAJOR << "." << VERSION_MINOR << " or later!" << endl;

    return 1;
  }

  // Lookup email server's IP address.
  lpHostEntry = gethostbyname(szSmtpServerName);
  if(!lpHostEntry)
  {
    cout << "Cannot find SMTP mail server " << szSmtpServerName << endl;

    return 1;
  }

  // Create a TCP/IP socket, no specific protocol
  hServer = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(hServer == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    cout << "Cannot open mail server socket" << endl;

    return 1;
  }

  // Get the mail service port
  lpServEntry = getservbyname("mail", 0);

  // Use the SMTP default port if no other port is specified
  if(!lpServEntry)
    iProtocolPort = htons(IPPORT_SMTP);
  else
    iProtocolPort = lpServEntry->s_port;

  // Setup a Socket Address structure
  SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  SockAddr.sin_port   = iProtocolPort;
  SockAddr.sin_addr   = *((LPIN_ADDR)*lpHostEntry->h_addr_list);

  // Connect the Socket
  if(connect(hServer, (PSOCKADDR) &SockAddr, sizeof(SockAddr)))
  {
    cout << "Error connecting to Server socket" << endl;

    return 1;
  }

  // Receive initial response from SMTP server
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() Reply");

  // Send HELO server.com
  sprintf(szMsgLine, "HELO %s%s", szSmtpServerName, CRLF);
  Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() HELO");
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() HELO");

  // Send MAIL FROM: <sender@mydomain.com>
  sprintf(szMsgLine, "MAIL FROM:<%s>%s", szFromAddr, CRLF);
  Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() MAIL FROM");
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() MAIL FROM");

  // Send RCPT TO: <receiver@domain.com>
  sprintf(szMsgLine, "RCPT TO:<%s>%s", szToAddr, CRLF);
  Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() RCPT TO");
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() RCPT TO");

  // Send DATA
  sprintf(szMsgLine, "DATA%s", CRLF);
  Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() DATA");
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() DATA");

  // Send all lines of message body (using supplied text file)
  MsgFile.getline(szLine, sizeof(szLine));             // Get first line

  do         // for each line of message text...
  {
    sprintf(szMsgLine, "%s%s", szLine, CRLF);
    Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() message-line");
    MsgFile.getline(szLine, sizeof(szLine)); // get next line.
  } while(MsgFile.good());

  // Send blank line and a period
  sprintf(szMsgLine, "%s.%s", CRLF, CRLF);
  Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() end-message");
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() end-message");

  // Send QUIT
  sprintf(szMsgLine, "QUIT%s", CRLF);
  Check(send(hServer, szMsgLine, strlen(szMsgLine), 0), "send() QUIT");
  Check(recv(hServer, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), 0), "recv() QUIT");

  // Report message has been sent
  cout << "Sent " << argv[4] << " as email message to " << szToAddr << endl;

  // Close server socket and prepare to exit.
  closesocket(hServer);

  WSACleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

but I think it is not for gmail. Because google mail uses different techniques. Link TLS SSL,

Comment: If you mean "either C or C++", you should probably say that rather than "C/C++". "C/C++" is a touchy subject.

Comment: Put up the code which didnt work for you, maybe it can be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need a library that support secure connection (GNUTLS). after establishing secure connection we can exchange authentication data and once we have accepted by the server we can send Email using our gmail credentials. Hope this will help other facing similar problem. Thanks for your kind replies.

Comment: adding a question in an answer then marking it as the thread answer is not the correct way. You should have updated your question or asked a second question.

Answer (score 3):

You need a library that implements SMTP.

For C++, I suggest you take a look at [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/category/Support), though I'm not entirely sure whether it's supported on Windows (there's a section on compiling with MingW, though, so I imagine that there's native Winsock support).

Alternatively, the C library [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) handles many protocols, including SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

Check out libquickmail (http://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/) which is based on libcurl which supports TLS.
Also it allows sending attachments and it can use authentication.
This library compiles with MinGW so it works on Windows.